# Has Stack Exchange stopped sending out emails for digests and question subscriptions?

Tags: bug, email, newsletter, subscription

I just noticed that I haven't received mails for my digest and question subscriptions for quite some time (at least 30 days). Is it just me or is this a global bug?

Comment: That sounds familiar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362300/i-subscribed-to-stack-overflow-feeds-to-my-email-but-havent-recieved-any-till-t

Comment: @rene Sound similar, but I have been subscribed for years.

Comment: When was the last mail you received, as in exact date?

Comment: @rene More than a month ago, as there's is nothing in my waste bin (which is emptied after 30 days).

Comment: What type of subscription do/did you have, exactly? If it was an existing subscription for receiving email about new questions in a tag, then: I received one of those emails from SE yesterday, and several within the last several days.

Comment: @Makyen The profile calls them "Question Subscriptions"

Answer (score 1):

All of my stackexchange newsletters were being flagged as spam by my provider, so I had to add "@stackoverflow.email" to my friend list.

Comment: Also, see what you are subscribed to: Email Settings https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current