# My question did not get an appropriate answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta, unanswered-questions

Regarding *[I subscribed to Stack Overflow feeds to my email but haven't received any till today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362300/i-subscribed-to-stack-overflow-feeds-to-my-email-but-havent-recieved-any-till-t)*:

I asked a question and I got some comments. I was not able to get an appropriate answer and I have the option to start a bounty.

Can I ask this question again? Starting a bounty would cost reputation points and doesn’t guarantee an answer. If there is no response from the users, my reputation points would be gone.

Comment: No, if you ask the question again it will be closed as a duplicate. There is no guarantee you get an answer, we don't have service level agreements. If you think it is an problem within the systems of Stack Exchange you can use the "contact us" link found in the footer. But even then you're not guaranteed or entitled to an answer. This is not a paid service, you're not a customer, you're a user of their platform, that is about it.

Comment: “Can I ask this question again?” - No; You can edit your question for free.  If you are not getting any answers then it’s probably your question.  In fact users asked for clarification mans it went unaddressed

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood bounties, your reputation points would be gone anyway, that's the way bounties work - you offer a reward to get an answer fitting certain criteria, you don't get a reward when that answer appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you ask it again, it will be closed as a duplicate, so please don't do that.

A bounty *may* help on a main network site, but my gut feeling is that here on Meta it's rather uncommon that bountying a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question is successful. (I should probably make that more substantial with a SEDE query.) Most users capable of answering this question right now will already have read it, but you never know: perhaps one of them was on vacation or not in the mood to visit Meta while your question was visible.

The [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) mentions another good possibility:

> To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.

If it's any consolation, you're not alone: there are [over 10,000 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) with no upvoted or accepted answers here.